# Do Noragami anime and manga share the same story line?

Tags: noragami

I have finished watching **Noragami** anime. Then I saw the Noragami manga. The anime has only 12 episodes but manga is ongoing. So if I want to read the manga from which chapter should I start? I mean after anime episode 12.

Comment: Just so you know, there are two season of Noragami and two OVA with two episode each, so there are 29 episodes

Comment: I didn't know. But in myanimelist and wikipedia i saw 12 episodes only

Comment: There are [Noragami](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/noragami), [Noragami OVA](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/noragami-ova), [Noragami Aragato](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/noragami-aragoto), [Noragami Aragato OVA](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/noragami-aragoto-ova)

Comment: https://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1470804

Answer (score 2):

### Do Noragami anime and manga follow the same storyline?

Yes, mostly.

- Noragami Ep 1-9 and beginning of 10 are canon.
- Noragami Aragoto Ep 1-6 are canon.

Noragami covered around the first 3 volumes of the manga, which covers the introduction of the 3 main characters.

### Where should I start to read after episode 12 of Noragami?

Considering Noragami covers roughly 3 volumes, you could start at chapter 12, the first chapter of volume 4.

The full canon view/reading order as told by [blessedyiki's tumblr](https://blessedyuki.tumblr.com/noragami-guide)

- Noragami (Ep 1-9 and beginning of 10)
- Noragami Aragoto (Ep 1-6 (you might want to read Chapter 23 for the full Kazuma/Ma clan backstory)
- Noragami Aragoto Episode 7 right until the opening
- Noragami OVA 2
- Noragami OVA 1
- Noragami Aragoto Episodes 7-13
- Chapter 40
- Noragami Aragoto OVA 2.

Answer (score 0):

if you watched seasons one and two of the anime, you should start reading from volume 11 of the manga. volume 10 is the end of season 2 , so noragami aragoto.